# C# setting web.config according to machine name

Tags: c#, web-config, app-config

Is it possible to change web.config (ASP.NET c#) file depending on Environment.MachineName? For example if I am running WebApp1 on dev.internal.net machine I need a connectionstring1 and webapp2 on Prod.external.net it is connectionstring2?

Thanks
R

Answer (score 1):

You can make several different connection strings like this:

```
    <add name="dev.internal.net" connectionString="Data Source=Location DB1;Initial       Catalog=DB Name;Integrated Security=True"/>
    <add name="Prod.external.net" connectionString="Data Source=Location DB1;Initial       Catalog=DB Name;Integrated Security=True"/>
```

You can make the name of the connection string as the Environment.MachineName to make it work.

***Some more information is on the following link:***

http://ayende.com/blog/135169/frictionless-development-web-config-and-connection-strings